# Append data from GET request to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, pug

I have a GET request that fetches some information from a server-side function and appends the data to a series of divs. However, when I console.log the response, I'm given the entire HTML for the website, as opposed to just the values I need.

Request

```
$('#verify').click(function() {
  var parameters = {
    firstName: $('#firstName').val(),
    lastName: $('#lastName').val(),
    email: $('#email').val() };
  $.get('/verify', parameters, function(data) {
    console.log(data); //Returns full body of HTML
    $('#firstLast').val(data); // Doesn't work
  });
});
```

Console.log

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head></head>
   <title>
      Demo
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
      <meta name="description" content="Demo project">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <style type="text/css"></style>
   </title>
   <body>
      <form method="post" action="post" id="plans" class="plans"><input id="firstName" type="text" name="firstName" value="rhys"><input id="lastName" type="text" name="lastName" value="edwards"><input id="email" type="text" name="email" value="@rhysedwards.com"><input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></form>
      <div id="firstLast">rhysedwards@rhysedwards.com: false</div>
      <div id="firstDotLast">rhys.edwards@rhysedwards.com: false</div>
      <div id="fInitialLastName">redwards@rhysedwards.com: false</div>
      <div id="fInitialDotLastName">r.edwards@rhysedwards.com: false</div>
      <div id="firstNameLInitial">rhyse@rhysedwards.com: false</div>
      <div id="firstNameDotLInitial">rhys.e@rhysedwards.com: false</div>
      <div id="firstNameOnly">rhys@rhysedwards.com: true</div>
      <div id="lastNameOnly">edwards@rhysedwards.com: false</div>
      <div id="firstNameUnderscoreLastName">rhys_edwards@rhysedwards.com: false</div>
      <div id="fInitialUnderscoreLastName">r_edwards@rhysedwards.com: false</div>
      <div id="firstNameUnderscoreLInitial">rhys_e@rhysedwards.com: false</div>
      <input id="verify" name="verify" value="verify" type="submit"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="./javascripts/script.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Inside that console.log is what I need:

```
<div id="firstLast">rhysedwards@rhysedwards.com: false</div>
<div id="firstDotLast">rhys.edwards@rhysedwards.com: false</div>
<div id="fInitialLastName">redwards@rhysedwards.com: false</div>
<div id="fInitialDotLastName">r.edwards@rhysedwards.com: false</div>     
<div id="firstNameLInitial">rhyse@rhysedwards.com: false</div>
<div id="firstNameDotLInitial">rhys.e@rhysedwards.com: false</div>
<div id="firstNameOnly">rhys@rhysedwards.com: true</div>
<div id="lastNameOnly">edwards@rhysedwards.com: false</div>
<div id="firstNameUnderscoreLastName">rhys_edwards@rhysedwards.com: false</div>
<div id="fInitialUnderscoreLastName">r_edwards@rhysedwards.com: false</div>
<div id="firstNameUnderscoreLInitial">rhys_e@rhysedwards.com: false</div>
```

Jade template:

```
block content
  form(method='post', action='post', class='plans', id='plans')
      input#firstName(type='text', name='firstName' value="rhys")
      input#lastName(type='text', name='lastName' value="edwards")
      input#email(type='text', name='email' value="@rhysedwards.com")
      input#submit(type='submit', name='submit', value='submit')
  #firstLast !{resultA}
  #firstDotLast !{resultB}
  #fInitialLastName !{resultC}
  #fInitialDotLastName !{resultD}
  #firstNameLInitial !{resultE}
  #firstNameDotLInitial !{resultF}
  #firstNameOnly !{resultG}
  #lastNameOnly !{resultH}
  #firstNameUnderscoreLastName !{resultI}
  #fInitialUnderscoreLastName !{resultJ}
  #firstNameUnderscoreLInitial !{resultK}
  input#verify(name='verify', value='verify', type='submit')
```

How do I get the div value for each of these from the `data` parameter?

Comment: Can you alter the server-side code to return only what you need?

Comment: If the response isn't giving you the data you need, then you need to modify the server function responsible for that.

Comment: Replacing .val with .html did the trick. Now to find out why a whole page is coming across. How joyful.

Comment: `block content`-> perhaps the template is extending a bigger layout, that includes the whole HTML chaff.

Comment: The issue was server-side, was using res.render instead of res.send. As such, it was sending back an entire template rather than an object.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are putting data to a `div` element use `$('#firstLast').html(data);`

```
.val() //is used for input elements
```

Comment: Great, that gets all the data on the page nicely. Cheers.